# How do I create and save gif of gray scale images with pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gif

I get an attribute error when I run this.
This code works for another RGB data set.
Python3.6, windows10

Code:

```
    image_dirs = glob.glob(denoised_dir + "/*")
    for_gif = []
    counter = 0 
    for (count, each_dir)in enumerate(image_dirs):
        images = glob.glob(each_dir + "/*")
        print(images)
        for image in images:
            counter += 1
            print(counter)
            print("processing denoised image:", image)
            im = Image.open(image)
            print("confirmimation", type(im))
            for_gif.append(im)
            print("counter", counter)
            print("for_gif", len(for_gif))
        print(for_gif)
        os.makedirs("./outputs/noise/gif/"+str(args.imgsize) + "_" + str(args.epochs) + "/" + args.image_type, exist_ok = True)
        print("directory created")
        for_gif[0].save("./outputs/noise/gif/"+str(args.imgsize) + "_" + str(args.epochs) + "/" + args.image_type + "/" + str(count) + ".gif", 
                        save_all=True, 
                        append_images=for_gif[1:],
                        optimize=False, 
                        duration=500, 
                        loop=0
                        )
```

and `for_gif` is as below:

```
[<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A07CF28>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0EC7F0>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0F08D0>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0F0BE0>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0FC080>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120
at 0x1FE2A0FC0F0>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0FC160>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0FC1D0>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0FC240>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0FC2B0>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0FC320>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0FC390>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0FC400>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0FC470>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0FC4E0>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0FC550>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0FC5C0>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0FC630>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0FC6A0>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0FC710>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0FC780>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0FC7F0>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0FC860>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0FC8D0>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=L size=120x120 at 0x1FE2A0FC940>]
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'palette'
```

Any advice will help me. Thanks.

Comment: Just a guess, but your images seem to be greyscale (`L`) but it seems to be looking for a palette so try changing to palette mode on open, i.e. `im = Image.open(image).convert('P')`

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry for the silence. it actually worked! thanks much

Answer (score 0):

Although `Image.open(image).convert('P')` works, I got better results when first converting to grayscale:
`Image.open(image).convert('L').convert('P')`

Without explicitly converting to grayscale the GIF resulted with some colored noise.

Answer (score -1):

I think the error occurred because you assigned `'L'` to `image mode`.

In my case, it works well in palette mode: `'P'`.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image 

images=[]
for frame_id in range(frame_num):
    # check image mode of target data
    im_pil = Image.open("frame_id"+ ".png").convert('P') 
    images.append(im_pil)

images[0].save('out.gif', save_all=True, append_images=images[1:])
```

Note that GIF files are always read as grayscale ('L') or palette mode ('P') images.

**Reference**

- [link added here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#gif)

Comment: I already have edited answer ans you reject it sand publish it as your own ,Bad things